# How can I pass variable from parent template to child template in Twig?

Tags: php, html, symfony, templates, twig

I'm working with Symfony and Twig and I can't find solution for the next problem:
in my parent template (**index.html.twig**) I have such code:

```
<noscript>
    {% block noscript %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <strong>{% block notice %}{{ notice_js_disabled }}{% endblock %}&nbsp;</strong>
        {% block message %}{{ js_disabled }}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
</noscript>
```

I have child template (**category.html.twig**) which extends **index.html.twig** template.

Can I pass value of `{{ notice_js_disabled }}` var from index template to category template?
`notice_js_disabled` is returned from my Symfony **indexAction** controller.

**UPD:**
The solution for my problem I founded, next:
I have made base templae, called main.html.twig, where I'm rendering element from the controller:

```
{% block header %}
   {{ render(controller('StoreBundle:Header:index')) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Then, on my index.html.twig file, I made next things:

```
{% extends 'Store/tpl/main.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <p class="currentPage" hidden>home</p>
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure is it correct solution, but it's work:)

Answer (score -2):

The only way in Twig you can pass some variable to a child template is by the **include** tag.

```
{# template.html will have access to the variables from the current context and the additional ones provided #}
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}

{% set vars = {'foo': 'bar'} %}
{% include 'template.html' with vars %}
```

However in this way you are not extending some parent template from the child, but you are doing the other way around: you are placing a submodule into the current template.

There are only a couple of variables which are **global** in symfony
You can set some custom global variables in configuration like described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html)

Otherwise you can use some predefined global variables, the app variable. ([check it out here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/templating.html#global-template-variables))

My personal advice is that you should review your application template logic.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeap, I already thinl about it - that I need to rewrite my templates, cause I'm on the wrong way. Thanks for helping )

Answer (score -3):

What you have to do is the following:
-Create A variable in the parent template

```
{% set notice_js_disabled = value_received_from_indexAction %}
```

After the template that you need that value

```
{{ notice_js_disabled }}
```

I hope it helps you