# Access form variable inside form_theme template

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a Twig problem which is I think quite simple to solve but I'm very new to Twig.

So we have a template product-options.html.twig with a form_theme line:

```
{% form_theme basketItemForm with 'FrontendBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}
```

Inside the fields.html.twig template I want to access the basketItemForm variable like:

```
{{ form_row(basketItemForm.myitem) }}
```

So inside the product-options.html.twig I can access the basketItemForm but how can I access it also with the included fields.html.twig template?

Comment: The form theme should be independent from the form that implements it. I don't think it's possible to refer to your basketForm in the theme. Can you maybe expand the question as to why you want to do it this way and what exactly you want to solve with this?

Comment: I didn't write the twig templates so maybe the current logic is not quite right. There is a plain html submit button inside the fields.html.twig but I want to use the form_row(basketItemForm.submitButton) instead of this plain html button. If I don't do that it will be written at the end of the base template when I use the form_end(basketItemForm) method.

Comment: im not sure but this may work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630130/how-can-i-pass-variable-from-parent-template-to-child-template-in-twig idk if this is an logical answer to yout question

Comment: Please add an answer and self-accept it instead of chancing the title to `solved`

Answer (score 0):

I think I was a little bit wrong so here is the solution.

In the fields.html.twig we have a widget block:

```
{% block _basket_item_add_widget %}
```

This widget will be called when we use the form_widget() in the product-options.html.twig template:

```
{{ form_widget(basketItemForm.add) }}
```

So in the widget block we have the plain html button and the element is set as rendered when we call it. :)